# Diffeomorphisms of generic foliations

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, topological-groups, foliations

Given a "generic" foliation with 1-dimensional leaves on a closed manifold M, I would like to claim that there are no diffeomorphisms of the manifold fixing the foliation, other than flowing along the leaves.

I am pretty sure that such a statement should be true (although it may require some additional hypotheses), but don't know how to prove it.

Could anyone suggest some relevant references (preferably ones which avoid going too deeply into the theory of foliations)?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  If you have a diffeomorphism that fixes the foliation, then almost by definition it must flow along the leaves.  If you specify a vector field for the foliation, and you want the flow to be along this vector field, I'm not sure this is true.  You could rescale the vector field and get a different flow that would still fix the foliation.  Trivial example, the real line is an integrable submanifold of itself.  The constant vector field determines a flow with constant velocity, which is certainly not the only diffeomorphism.

Comment: I think you can always find a vector field whose flow results in the desired diffeomorphism though.  To do this, define the vector field to be the pushforward of the vector field with constant velocity that points along the flow.  Then take the pushforward of this vector field with respect to the diffeomorphism. You can then show that two points that differ infinitesimally will travel to their respective points in the same amount of time.  I'm not sure about possible singular points in the flow though, this could be an issue (the flow could stop somewhere).

Comment: Please, clarify what "fixing the foliation" means: Do you mean "sending leaves to leaves"? (This is usually called "preserving the foliation".) Also, what is your notion of "generic"? For instance, is an irrational foliation of the flat 2-torus by affine lines regarded as "generic"? There will be affine self-maps of the torus preserving the foliation but not the individual leaves.

Comment: My apologies for the confusion: I mean "sending leaves to leaves".  I am not sure precisely what generic ought to mean (I guess that this is part of the question). If one views a 1-dim foliation as a map from the manifold to the (projectivized) tangent bundle, then maybe we could definite "generic" as "comeager in the space of such maps" (endowed with a suitable topology). This appears to rule out the example of irrational foliations of the flat torus.

Comment: So, from painful experience in symplectic geometry: you really have to watch out for strong claims about foliations.

Comment: Are you asserting that if a diffeomorphism fixes each leaf of the foliation, it is path-connected to the identity map via diffeomorphisms that do the same?

Comment: For 1-dimensional foliations, there are silly examples; if a foliation of $M$ admits a diffeomorphism from $M$ to $N\times \mathbb R$, for example, you can reflect the $\mathbb R$ component.  I don't think "genericity" is the way to get rid of examples like that; I think what you want is "if a diffeomorphism is path-connected to the identity, and the endpoints fix each leaf of $\mathcal F$, there is a path of diffeomorphisms where each one fixes each leaf of $\mathcal F$."

Comment: A more serious counterexample would be a Dehn twist on a surface where you have an annulus of concentric circles (or really I mean homologous in the annulus, e.g. meridians on a torus count).  Then a Dehn twist could be performed in that annular neighborhood, i.e. a diffeomorphism not path-connected to the identity.  However I will stop here as I'm not sure I'm talking about the right question.

Comment: @ElizabethS.Q.Goodman Thanks for your helpful comments; I think your counterexamples are addressing a different question from the one I had in mind.  I am asking the following: fix a (generic) foliation on a manifold (say the torus). Then any diffeomorphism which sends the foliation to itself must be isotopic to the identity through diffeomorphisms which do the same.

Comment: It seems to be that the Dehn twist actually changes the foliation (i.e. the set of leaves before the Dehn twist is not the same as the set of leaves after the Dehn twist)